# inspect.signature with PEP 563

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.7, static-typing

The following code:

```
import inspect
from typing import NamedTuple

class Example(NamedTuple):
    a: str

if __name__== "__main__":
    signature: inspect.Signature = inspect.signature(Example)
    print(signature)
```

outputs:

```
(a: str)
```

However when enabling [PEP 563 – Postponed Evaluation of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```
from __future__ import annotations
import inspect
from typing import NamedTuple

class Example(NamedTuple):
    a: str

if __name__== "__main__":
    signature: inspect.Signature = inspect.signature(Example)
    print(signature)
```

The output is:

```
(a: 'str')
```

How can I get the exact same object of type `inspect.Signature` with PEP 563 like without it?

Comment: The **whole point** of that PEP is to *not* get the same object... You'll have to *evaluate* the string using `exec` or the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of using PEP 536 is to *not* evaluate the annotations unless needed. The signature merely reports on the annotations.

If for your purposes you need to have the annotations resolved, you have to do so yourself. PEP 536 tells [documents how you do this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#resolving-type-hints-at-runtime):

> For code that uses type hints, the `typing.get_type_hints(obj, globalns=None, localns=None)` function correctly evaluates expressions back from its string form.
>
> [...]
>
> For code which uses annotations for other purposes, a regular eval(ann, globals, locals) call is enough to resolve the annotation.

You could even use the [`typing.get_type_hints()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to assign back to `__annotations__` before getting the signature:

```
import typing

Example.__new__.__annotations__ = typing.get_type_hints(Example.__new__)
signature: inspect.Signature = inspect.signature(Example)
```

Doing this is safe even if `from __future__ import annotations` had not been used.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'll award the bounty tomorrow, because for some reason stackoverflow does not allow me to do so right now without waiting 3 hours. :rolleyes:

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually use `eval` to get the same behaviour:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import inspect
from typing import NamedTuple

class Example(NamedTuple):
    a: str

signature: inspect.Signature = inspect.signature(Example)
print(signature)

# extra bit
globalns = getattr(Example, '__globals__', {})
for param in list(signature.parameters.values()):
  if isinstance(param.annotation, str):
    param._annotation = eval(param.annotation, globalns)

print(signature)
```

You will get:

```
(a: 'str')
(a: str)
```

Alternatively you can modify `__annotations__` before calling `inspect.signature(obj)`, but I am finding it too hard, because I need to cover multiple different cases.

Answer by @Martijn Pieters misses one detail about `typing.get_type_hints`:

> if necessary adds Optional[t] if a default value equal to None is set

Example:

```py
# without imporing annotations from __future__
import inspect
import typing

def func(a: str=None): pass
print(inspect.signature(func))
func.__annotations__ = typing.get_type_hints(func)
print(inspect.signature(func))
```

You will get:

```
(a: str = None)
(a: Union[str, NoneType] = None)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's run a different example:

```
signature: inspect.Signature = inspect.signature(Example)
print(signature)
print(Example.__annotations__)
```

This prints:

```
(a: str)
OrderedDict([('a', <class 'str'>)])
```

So far so good, we have or `Signature` and our `__anotations__` as we expected.

Now let's do the same for the second example, it prints:

```
(a: 'str')
OrderedDict([('a', ForwardRef('str'))])
```

So you're not getting **the same** `Signature` here. One gives you the actual class and the other a `typing.ForwardRef` to the class.

Comment: It's vital to note that the *only* reason the `a` annotation postpones to a `typing.ForwardRef` (which is quite unusual) rather than a `str` (which is the usual case) is that the `Example` class subclasses `typing.NamedTuple`. Ergo, you see `typing`-specific postponement here. In general, activating `from __future__ import annotations` postpones annotations to simple unevaluated strings – which is much more sensible than postponing to higher-level objects like `typing.ForwardRef`, since the whole point of PEP 563 is to reduce the space and time costs associated with annotations. *Annnnnyway.*

Comment: Ok, the comment upstairs is one those useful things you happen to find only by chance from time to time, so if @CecilCurry agrees I would like to edit my answer and include the comment as some kind of addendum